Installing software on a different directory in RHEL 8.x
I am currently using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.9 for installing some software. Now, we know that Linux can have multiple hard drives like sda, sdb and sdc. I want to install software like Java amazon corretto 17, NGINX etc. on sdb or sdc instead of sda. I have searched about this but I am not sure how to implement on the server. If you guys could show the exact steps, that would be great. Also I am trying to do offline installation as I have the files locally downloaded on my pc and uploaded to the server.

Please [edit] your question and show us your partitioning setup. Which disk is being used where? What is your / mounted on? How are these other disks mounted?

The partitions I have is sda, sdb and sdc. Since we won't be focusing on sda, sdb has only one partition which is sdb1 /mnt/sdb

Please edit the question, don't answer in comments. Add the information to the question so everyone can see. And please answer all the questions. We need to know the current setup in order to help. Would installing ALL software on sdb be an acceptable solution?

Software is not installed on /dev/sd*, it is installed on mounted file systems. Most packages are installed under /usr (or /opt, /usr/local, etc.), so if /usr is spread across /dev/sda* and /dev/sdb* and /dev/sdc* (for example, using lvm), then you're good. If you have every partition on the physical disks mount as a separate file system, then what you're asking for might be possible but would be a nightmare to manage.

You don't normally use storage devices directly in any operating system, even in Windows.
You first partition disks and then in the case of Linux you mount the desired partitions into the desired mount points (in Linux it's simply a directory, normally empty).
There are many ways to partition:

plain MBR
plain GPT
MBR/GPT and any combination of LVM/LUKS on top of it.

After partitioning, you invoke sudo mkfs.desired_filesystem /dev/partition.
No one but you knows what's appropriate for your use case. This stackexchange website is meant to solve specific issues, not provide you with a step by step tutorial of how tasks like this could be accomplished. Your first learn, try to apply your knowledge, make sure people haven't already dealt with something similar by Googling for it and if you find nothing appropriate, you ask a question.
After mounting the drive, you may attempt to install software to this path given that this software knows how to work from an arbitrary path. Many applications simply cannot and expect to be run from predefined locations. Symlinking will help.
TBO, even ChatGPT or Claude.ai could have given you almost the exact same answer. Being that lazy in 2024 is not a good trait.

Thanks for your feedback. Online searches give different approaches and I have tried few steps and it did not work for me that is why I asked step by step tutorial. I thought this was an open site to post whatever issues we are facing.

If you have the mount point created, with rpm can work:
rpm -ivh --prefix=/mnt/software xxx-x.x.x.rpm

But you have to make the partition of /dev/sdc and mount it.

This will only work if the application doesn't hardcode paths to internal resources.

Hadn't thought of it that way.

Thank you! I will get back to you with my feedback!

I installed Java Amazon corretto and it is working fine but when I tried to do the same for OpenSearch, it is throwing some error like warning: opensearch-1.3.6-linux-x64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID 9310d3fc: NOKEY
error: package opensearch is not relocatable
